# Having no derangements --- any advantage?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Is there any problem-solving advantage when a sequence has **no derangements?**
**Edit: Yes.** It turns out that using the Sieve of Eratosthenes, we can show that the divisors are a derangement because each number has a unique cycle. However, by keeping the target numbers in strict order, we find the divisors match their respective multiples. Thus it is a form of non-derangement.

**Edit** Perhaps the non-derangements are just a by-product of the argument that we find primes in $(m-k,k] \iff k|m$?

In an Erd\"os proof of Sylvester-Schur he identifies a few exceptions which I contend would not happen if his sequence had no derangements.

**Edit** I need this answered for some original research; not to pick apart an Erd\"os proof. It was just a handy example. Within the factors of the binomials, we show no derangements above the single line:
$$\text{Let }m=\{nk:1<n\leq k+2\}\text{, for (say) }k=5,$$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
\dbinom{m}{k}&p|(\cdot)\in(k,m]&p|(\cdot)\in(m-k,m]\\ \hline
\dbinom{10}{5}&7&7\\ 
\dbinom{15}{5}&7,11, 13&11, 13\\ 
\dbinom{20}{5}&17, 19&17, 19\\
\dbinom{25}{5}&7,11,23&23\\
\dbinom{30}{5}&7,13,29&29\\
\dbinom{35}{5}&7,11,17,31&31 \\ \hline \hline
\dbinom{28}{5}&7,13&\varnothing\\ 
\dbinom{28}{4}&5^2, 7, 13&\varnothing\\ \hline
\end{array},
$$
where $p|(\cdot)\in(k,m]$ indicates that p divides some element within the non-derangement. First line below the single line shows an exception when $k\not|\text{ }m $ and last line shows an exception when a non-derangement exceeds $k+2$ limit.

Comment: Do you mean a sequence of one item, so that there are no permutations without a fixed point?

Comment: IMHO, your question is too general and will generate answers of the same style,without usefulness for the community . You should give an example of the type of sequence you are thinking about in order to narrow the field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referring to derangements, I'm assuming you are talking about moving terms around, as should be possible with sequences.

My imagination says that if you rearrange a sequence, it may no longer be a sequence.  Or at least it might not be a sequence that has any meaning or could be made any sense out of.

So... the advantage is most likely that it makes sense and is still the sequence you are looking at.

Comment: I'm also referring to rotational derangements such a $\{1,2,3\}$ shifted left one to become $\{2,3,1\}$. Both are mod 3.

Comment: @FredKline My point is whether or not your even dealing with the same sequence anymore.  For example, the Fibonacci sequence is special because of the recursive relationship.  You could say $\lbrace1,2,3\rbrace$ is special because it goes in order from least to greatest from 1 to 3.  But none of that seems to matter after derangement, so what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: $\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\},\{7,8,9\}\dots$ where each is $\{1,2,3\}$ and their mod 3 value is their position in the sublist.

Comment: @FredKline Yes, that could be useful for a problem, for example, but does it make much sense if I rearrange them in the following manner: $$\lbrace2,1,3\rbrace,\lbrace4,6,5\rbrace,\lbrace9,7,8\rbrace$$ in mod 3, none are equal, nor do they appear to have any relationship other than covering the first 9 whole numbers.  What's the point in doing this in the first place?

Comment: @FredKline Sure, I understand.  But if you truly feel the answer is not deserving in the future, let the points go to waste.  High rep users are not on this site to gain more rep (we have plenty), we are here to assist in your mathematical journey.

Comment: I found your answer intriguing enough to search for combinatoric functions that maintain the non-derangements and found a beauty. So your answer was the perfect trigger, and worthy of the points. Tnanks.